# Parse a date like 2012-11-07T00:00:00

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I get from my client a date in this format:

2012-11-07T00:00:00 (yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00)

How can I parse it into a *Date* object?

My first option is:

- getting the first 10 characters (2012-11-07)
- split that by "-"
- creating new Date(splitted[0],splitted[1],splitter[2])

I know that such a question is obvious and over-answered, not only in Stack Overflow, but I want to:

- know a better practice WITHOUT any library, pure JS ( Date.parse() ? )
- the same with a widely used date library / framework for nodeJS

Comment: Obvious and over-answered but you'll ask it anyway...?!

Comment: A mere search on StackOverflow gave me about 20 answers to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> var d = new Date('2012-11-07T00:00:00')

Comment: You will run into issues due to the timezones.


new Date("2017-06-11T00:00:00") = Sat Jun 10 2017 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)


Notice the string is June 11th but the parsed date is June 10th.


See this article.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238261/convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-fffz-to-datetime-in-javascript-manually