# Convert yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ to DateTime in JavaScript manually

Tags: javascript, datetime, string-formatting, nsdateformatter

I receive from a Webservice a String with a date in this format:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ
```

I need to convert that String with JavaScript to a normal DateTime but without using the new `Date('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')` because I'm using an old version of JavaScript that not support that conversion. I can split that string and get the:

- Year
- Month
- Days
- Time

but how to manipulate the time zone `"fffZ"` Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your javascript environment?

Comment: `fffZ` is not a time zone - the time zone is `Z` ([Zulu time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_time), which means UTC), and `fff` are three decimals that belong to the seconds part (`ss.fff`) - if you take all three together, they form the milliseconds part.

Comment: Android 2.3 (Using PhoneGap and ChildBrowser)

Comment: This is my real String 2013-01-08T17:16:36.000Z

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've founded the solution. Please check http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/

```
Date.prototype.setISO8601 = function (string) {
    var regexp = "([0-9]{4})(-([0-9]{2})(-([0-9]{2})" +
        "(T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:([0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]+))?)?" +
        "(Z|(([-+])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})))?)?)?)?";
    var d = string.match(new RegExp(regexp));

    var offset = 0;
    var date = new Date(d[1], 0, 1);

    if (d[3]) { date.setMonth(d[3] - 1); }
    if (d[5]) { date.setDate(d[5]); }
    if (d[7]) { date.setHours(d[7]); }
    if (d[8]) { date.setMinutes(d[8]); }
    if (d[10]) { date.setSeconds(d[10]); }
    if (d[12]) { date.setMilliseconds(Number("0." + d[12]) * 1000); }
    if (d[14]) {
        offset = (Number(d[16]) * 60) + Number(d[17]);
        offset *= ((d[15] == '-') ? 1 : -1);
    }

    offset -= date.getTimezoneOffset();
    time = (Number(date) + (offset * 60 * 1000));
    this.setTime(Number(time));
}
```

Comment: and how do you use this? `Date.setISO8601('2010-01-02T00:00:01')` this way  ?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a one liner from [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/files/pretty.js):

```
var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
```

Comment: `new Date("1987/02/28 23:11:81.333 ")` gives me `Invalid Date`

Comment: I think this answer needs to be explained as it need an example and it ends in a comma

Answer (score 0):

If you know it will be of this form ([ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), you can parse with RegExp or string methods. Here is a RegExp example that lets you use timezone `Z`, `+hh` or `+hh:mm`.

```
var dateString = '2013-01-08T17:16:36.000Z';

var ISO_8601_re = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(?:\.(\d{3}))?(Z|[\+-]\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)$/,
    m = dateString .match(ISO_8601_re);

var year = +m[1],
    month = +m[2],
    dayOfMonth = +m[3],
    hour = +m[4],
    minute = +m[5],
    second = +m[6],
    ms = +m[7], // +'' === 0
    timezone = m[8];

if (timezone === 'Z') timezone = 0;
else timezone = timezone.split(':'), timezone = +(timezone[0][0]+'1') * (60*(+timezone[0].slice(1)) + (+timezone[1] || 0));
// timezone is now minutes

// your prefered way to construct
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setUTCFullYear(year);
myDate.setUTCMonth(month - 1);
myDate.setUTCDate(dayOfMonth);
myDate.setUTCHours(hour);
myDate.setUTCMinutes(minute + timezone); // timezone offset set here, after hours
myDate.setUTCSeconds(second);
myDate.setUTCMilliseconds(ms);

console.log(myDate); // Tue Jan 08 2013 17:16:36 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Comment: @kennebec I didn't miss it, I just failed at copying the right thing

Answer (score -3):

[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) has the answer to this and many other date problems you might have.
While it isn't clear where and how you will user the needed date, neither the wanted format, I think momentjs can give you some of the needed tasks
I would add the module to my solution and use as (below is parse.com cloud code):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("momentFormat", function(request, response){
    var message;

    var date = momento('2013-01-08T17:16:36.000Z');
    response.success("original format date: " + date.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ") + " new format date: " + date.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
});
```

Output:

```
{"result":"original format date: 2013-01-08T17:16:36.000+00:00 new format date: Tuesday, January 8th 2013, 5:16:36 pm"}
```

Comment: right.... I was too quick on answering this.  For sure momentjs could help you a lot.. but yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ is no fully reconized.  something to do with the fff part.... but my main point is that using momentjs you can overcome many issues.