# how to get All values from a json file using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

here is my code that works fine for what it is

```
(function ($) {
  $('input').on('click', function () {
    $('.table ul').remove();
    $("#guildwars2").val();
    // selection made
    var zip = $('#guildwars2 option:selected').text();
    // guild wars 2 guild api key

    var apkey = ('?access_token=...');
    $.getJSON("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/guild/645BD706-FC0B-41B5-921C-ED07E6A7D8FC/" + zip + apkey + "", function (data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        if (zip == 'members'){
          items.push('<li id=" ' + key + '"=>' + val.name + " - " + val.rank + '</li>');
        } else if (zip == 'ranks'){
          items.push('<li id="' + key + '"><br><span class="imagepng">' + val.icon + ' - ' + val.id + '</li>');
        } else if (zip == 'log'){
          items.push('<li id="' + key + '"><br><span class="id">' + val.time + '</span><br><span class="time">' + val.type + ' By ' + val.user + '</span></li>');
        }
      });
      if (items.length < 1) {
        items.push('<li>No results , try again!</li>');
      }
      $ul = $('<ul />').appendTo('.table');
      $ul.append(items);
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

but how do I get all data instead of val.name or val.rank

I have tried

```
(function ($) {
  $('input').on('click', function () {
    $('.table ul').remove();
    $("#guildwars2").val();
    // selection made
    var zip = $('#guildwars2 option:selected').text();
    // guild wars 2 guild api key

    var apkey = ('?access_token=...');
    $.getJSON("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/guild/645BD706-FC0B-41B5-921C-ED07E6A7D8FC/" + zip + apkey + "", function (data) {

      var items = [];
      $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '"><br><span class="id">' + val + '</span></li>');
      });
      if (items.length < 1) {
        items.push('<li>No results , try again!</li>');
      }
      $ul = $('<ul />').appendTo('.table');
      $ul.append(items);
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

but this just returns object,object for all values

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help you, without some example JSON.

Comment: Please hurry and create a new API key. Since you've shared it with us, it has now been compromised and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the objects returned in the array:

```
var apkey = ('?access_token=...');

$("#guildwars2").on("change",function() {
  var zip = $('option:selected',this).text(),
  $.getJSON("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/guild/645BD706-FC0B-41B5-921C-ED07E6A7D8FC/" + zip + apkey, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, obj) {
      items.push('<ul id="' + index + '">')
      for (o in obj) {
        items.push('<li>' + o + ":"+obj[o] + '</li>');
      }
      items.push('</ul>');
    });
    $("#container").html(items.length>0?items.join(""):"Nothing found")
  });
});
```

Example:

```js
data = [{
    "name": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "rank": "Leader",
    "joined": "2013-05-27T20:33:01.000Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "rank": "Leader",
    "joined": "2015-11-24T19:01:29.000Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "sassy.8241",
    "rank": "Leader",
    "joined": null
  },
  {
    "name": "nytri.3401",
    "rank": "Officer",
    "joined": "2015-08-12T17:13:53.000Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "Demonic Angel.3496",
    "rank": "Donor",
    "joined": "2015-11-27T00:26:45.000Z"
  },

  {
    "id": 3412,
    "time": "2016-09-11T23:03:02.000Z",
    "type": "invite_declined",
    "user": "magic magician master.8614",
    "declined_by": "magic magician master.8614"
  },
  {
    "id": 3225,
    "time": "2016-05-16T22:24:46.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Co Leader",
    "new_rank": "Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 3224,
    "time": "2016-05-16T22:24:37.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Co Leader",
    "new_rank": "Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 2967,
    "time": "2015-12-31T21:55:27.000Z",
    "type": "motd",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "motd": "Welcome friends to the family "
  },
  {
    "id": 2948,
    "time": "2015-12-20T13:01:13.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Demonic Angel.3496"
  },
  {
    "id": 2909,
    "time": "2015-11-28T17:53:54.000Z",
    "type": "motd",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "motd": "Welcome To Our Friendly Guild, If you need any help in any area please ask in chat and i am sure someone will help you.\nalso if you want to do dungeon runs ect please ask an officer and we can arrange a full guild run.\nWelcome our newest member sarge :P\n\nMrs Tech is putting up Christmas decorations  tonight will be on asap"
  },
  {
    "id": 2904,
    "time": "2015-11-27T09:56:40.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Leader",
    "new_rank": "Co Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 2903,
    "time": "2015-11-27T09:56:22.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Co Leader",
    "new_rank": "Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 2901,
    "time": "2015-11-27T00:26:46.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Demonic Angel.3496",
    "invited_by": "Srg Farr.3045"
  },
  {
    "id": 2886,
    "time": "2015-11-24T19:01:55.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Co Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 2885,
    "time": "2015-11-24T19:01:30.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045"
  },
  {
    "id": 2883,
    "time": "2015-11-24T19:01:05.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "invited_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 2882,
    "time": "2015-11-24T18:30:41.000Z",
    "type": "kick",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "kicked_by": "Srg Farr.3045"
  },
  {
    "id": 2880,
    "time": "2015-11-23T23:16:20.000Z",
    "type": "kick",
    "user": "Amsera.8179",
    "kicked_by": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 2879,
    "time": "2015-11-23T23:16:17.000Z",
    "type": "kick",
    "user": "Devishly Shell.6102",
    "kicked_by": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 2878,
    "time": "2015-11-23T22:26:12.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Devishly Shell.6102",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Member"
  },
  {
    "id": 2877,
    "time": "2015-11-23T22:26:09.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Amsera.8179",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Member"
  },
  {
    "id": 2876,
    "time": "2015-11-23T22:25:24.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Officer",
    "new_rank": "Co Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 2858,
    "time": "2015-11-15T01:28:56.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 2857,
    "time": "2015-11-15T01:28:34.000Z",
    "type": "motd",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "motd": "Welcome To Our Friendly Guild, If you need any help in any area please ask in chat and i am sure someone will help you.\n\nalso if you want to do dungeon runs ect please ask an officer and we can arrange a full guild run.\n\n\nWelcome our newest member sarge :P"
  },
  {
    "id": 2855,
    "time": "2015-11-14T22:56:47.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045"
  },
  {
    "id": 2853,
    "time": "2015-11-14T22:56:13.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Srg Farr.3045",
    "invited_by": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 2719,
    "time": "2015-08-29T13:33:44.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "daily_login",
    "total_participants": 0,
    "participants": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2717,
    "time": "2015-08-29T00:44:26.000Z",
    "type": "stash",
    "user": "nytri.3401",
    "operation": "deposit",
    "item_id": 39495,
    "count": 1,
    "coins": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2714,
    "time": "2015-08-29T00:44:17.000Z",
    "type": "stash",
    "user": "nytri.3401",
    "operation": "deposit",
    "item_id": 20601,
    "count": 1,
    "coins": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2711,
    "time": "2015-08-29T00:44:14.000Z",
    "type": "stash",
    "user": "nytri.3401",
    "operation": "deposit",
    "item_id": 20660,
    "count": 1,
    "coins": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2708,
    "time": "2015-08-29T00:44:12.000Z",
    "type": "stash",
    "user": "nytri.3401",
    "operation": "deposit",
    "item_id": 20724,
    "count": 1,
    "coins": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2705,
    "time": "2015-08-29T00:44:10.000Z",
    "type": "stash",
    "user": "nytri.3401",
    "operation": "deposit",
    "item_id": 20506,
    "count": 1,
    "coins": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2698,
    "time": "2015-08-26T13:34:44.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "daily_login",
    "total_participants": 0,
    "participants": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2689,
    "time": "2015-08-25T13:37:19.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "daily_login",
    "total_participants": 0,
    "participants": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2684,
    "time": "2015-08-22T22:02:59.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 17,
    "action": "complete"
  },
  {
    "id": 2681,
    "time": "2015-08-21T13:35:32.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "daily_login",
    "total_participants": 0,
    "participants": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2678,
    "time": "2015-08-20T13:37:50.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "daily_login",
    "total_participants": 0,
    "participants": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2665,
    "time": "2015-08-19T22:08:23.000Z",
    "type": "stash",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "operation": "deposit",
    "item_id": 21161,
    "count": 1,
    "coins": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2662,
    "time": "2015-08-19T22:02:59.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 17,
    "action": "queued",
    "user": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 2660,
    "time": "2015-08-19T22:02:36.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "gifted",
    "total_participants": 1,
    "participants": [
      "sassy.8241"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2656,
    "time": "2015-08-19T20:34:16.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "gifted",
    "total_participants": 1,
    "participants": [
      "nytri.3401"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2653,
    "time": "2015-08-18T13:36:31.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "daily_login",
    "total_participants": 0,
    "participants": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2641,
    "time": "2015-08-15T14:51:05.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 58,
    "action": "complete"
  },
  {
    "id": 2636,
    "time": "2015-08-13T14:51:04.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 58,
    "action": "queued",
    "user": "nytri.3401"
  },
  {
    "id": 2633,
    "time": "2015-08-13T13:17:09.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 16,
    "action": "complete"
  },
  {
    "id": 2629,
    "time": "2015-08-12T23:10:40.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Devishly Shell.6102",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Officer",
    "new_rank": "Donor"
  },
  {
    "id": 2628,
    "time": "2015-08-12T23:10:38.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Amsera.8179",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Officer",
    "new_rank": "Donor"
  },
  {
    "id": 2627,
    "time": "2015-08-12T23:10:15.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "nytri.3401",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 2626,
    "time": "2015-08-12T22:04:34.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 16,
    "action": "sped_up",
    "user": "nytri.3401"
  },
  {
    "id": 2624,
    "time": "2015-08-12T22:04:31.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 16,
    "action": "sped_up",
    "user": "nytri.3401"
  },
  {
    "id": 2622,
    "time": "2015-08-12T22:04:28.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 16,
    "action": "sped_up",
    "user": "nytri.3401"
  },
  {
    "id": 2620,
    "time": "2015-08-12T22:04:18.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 16,
    "action": "queued",
    "user": "nytri.3401"
  },
  {
    "id": 2618,
    "time": "2015-08-12T22:03:59.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "gifted",
    "total_participants": 1,
    "participants": [
      "nytri.3401"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2616,
    "time": "2015-08-12T17:13:54.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "nytri.3401"
  },
  {
    "id": 2613,
    "time": "2015-08-12T13:10:05.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "nytri.3401",
    "invited_by": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 2601,
    "time": "2015-08-02T13:35:36.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "daily_login",
    "total_participants": 0,
    "participants": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2599,
    "time": "2015-08-02T10:30:48.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 53,
    "action": "complete"
  },
  {
    "id": 2593,
    "time": "2015-07-31T10:08:13.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 6,
    "action": "complete"
  },
  {
    "id": 2591,
    "time": "2015-07-30T18:08:46.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 53,
    "action": "queued",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 2589,
    "time": "2015-07-30T18:08:13.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 6,
    "action": "queued",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 2444,
    "time": "2015-04-12T07:50:51.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 15,
    "action": "complete"
  },
  {
    "id": 2441,
    "time": "2015-04-11T13:29:45.000Z",
    "type": "upgrade",
    "upgrade_id": 15,
    "action": "queued",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 2432,
    "time": "2015-04-04T13:35:06.000Z",
    "type": "influence",
    "activity": "daily_login",
    "total_participants": 0,
    "participants": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2393,
    "time": "2015-03-11T20:54:03.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "magic magician master.8614",
    "invited_by": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 2235,
    "time": "2014-08-16T16:36:38.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Devishly Shell.6102",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 2233,
    "time": "2014-08-16T16:36:33.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Amsera.8179",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 2010,
    "time": "2014-03-01T16:56:20.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Co Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 1645,
    "time": "2013-05-27T20:33:09.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 1641,
    "time": "2013-05-27T20:33:02.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "invited_by": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 1631,
    "time": "2013-05-21T14:40:05.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Devishly Shell.6102"
  },
  {
    "id": 1474,
    "time": "2013-01-26T22:03:40.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Amsera.8179"
  },
  {
    "id": 1470,
    "time": "2013-01-26T22:03:33.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Amsera.8179",
    "invited_by": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 1438,
    "time": "2012-11-28T00:17:49.000Z",
    "type": "kick",
    "user": "Manus.2795",
    "kicked_by": "Manus.2795"
  },
  {
    "id": 1433,
    "time": "2012-11-25T18:37:30.000Z",
    "type": "invite_declined",
    "user": "AdowG.8905",
    "declined_by": "AdowG.8905"
  },
  {
    "id": 1428,
    "time": "2012-11-22T20:08:33.000Z",
    "type": "kick",
    "user": "Sheetaan.4135",
    "kicked_by": "Sheetaan.4135"
  },
  {
    "id": 1420,
    "time": "2012-11-21T15:08:19.000Z",
    "type": "kick",
    "user": "Chrescerya.4659",
    "kicked_by": "Chrescerya.4659"
  },
  {
    "id": 1409,
    "time": "2012-11-20T15:41:42.000Z",
    "type": "kick",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "kicked_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 1407,
    "time": "2012-11-20T15:41:06.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Co Leader",
    "new_rank": "Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 1405,
    "time": "2012-11-20T15:41:02.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Officer",
    "new_rank": "Co Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 1369,
    "time": "2012-11-20T01:49:25.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Manus.2795",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 1367,
    "time": "2012-11-20T01:48:33.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Manus.2795"
  },
  {
    "id": 1364,
    "time": "2012-11-20T01:41:01.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Manus.2795",
    "invited_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 1230,
    "time": "2012-11-18T17:20:55.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Sheetaan.4135",
    "changed_by": "Chrescerya.4659",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 1228,
    "time": "2012-11-18T17:16:10.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Sheetaan.4135"
  },
  {
    "id": 1179,
    "time": "2012-11-17T22:45:46.000Z",
    "type": "invite_declined",
    "user": "Finnguala.6921",
    "declined_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 1058,
    "time": "2012-11-16T20:02:55.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Finnguala.6921",
    "invited_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 1054,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:54:15.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Chrescerya.4659",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Donor",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 1052,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:53:49.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Chrescerya.4659"
  },
  {
    "id": 1048,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:44:17.000Z",
    "type": "invite_declined",
    "user": "Finnguala.6921",
    "declined_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 1045,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:44:05.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Finnguala.6921",
    "invited_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 1042,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:43:54.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Devishly Shell.6102",
    "invited_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 1039,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:43:36.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "AdowG.8905",
    "invited_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 1037,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:42:53.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Co Leader",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 1006,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:34:17.000Z",
    "type": "motd",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "motd": "Welcome To Our Friendly Guild, If you need any help in any area please ask in chat and i am sure someone will help you.\n\nalso if you want to do dungeon runs ect please ask an officer and we can arrange a full guild run."
  },
  {
    "id": 1004,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:32:41.000Z",
    "type": "motd",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "motd": "Welcome old and new friends have fun thats what its all about"
  },
  {
    "id": 1001,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:31:58.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Chrescerya.4659",
    "invited_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 999,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:31:29.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Leader",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 997,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:31:23.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Officer",
    "new_rank": "Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 995,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:31:17.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Member",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 993,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:31:15.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Officer",
    "new_rank": "Member"
  },
  {
    "id": 991,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:31:12.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "changed_by": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "old_rank": "Member",
    "new_rank": "Officer"
  },
  {
    "id": 989,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:30:52.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Leader",
    "new_rank": "Member"
  },
  {
    "id": 987,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:30:01.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "changed_by": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "Member",
    "new_rank": "Leader"
  },
  {
    "id": 985,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:29:37.000Z",
    "type": "joined",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560"
  },
  {
    "id": 982,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:29:23.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Sheetaan.4135",
    "invited_by": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 979,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:28:46.000Z",
    "type": "invited",
    "user": "Scotty The Engineer.1560",
    "invited_by": "sassy.8241"
  },
  {
    "id": 971,
    "time": "2012-11-16T19:28:21.000Z",
    "type": "rank_change",
    "user": "sassy.8241",
    "old_rank": "none",
    "new_rank": "leader"
  }

], items = [];

$.each(data, function(index, obj) {
  items.push('<ul id="' + index + '">')
  for (o in obj) {
    items.push('<li>' + o + ":"+obj[o] + '</li>');
  }
  items.push('</ul>');
});

if (items.length < 1) {
  items.push('<ul><li>No results , try again!</li></ul>');
}
else $('#res').html(items.join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: that works ok for members but not for ranks or log as they now come up undefined :( but ty for giving me a lead to work on

Comment: Please see update. I missed that your first example worked

Comment: To convert the time use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238261/convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-fffz-to-datetime-in-javascript-manually

Comment: awesome ty so much, hope i am not being to much of a pain if i could just ask instead of adding to the list how to replace the list when i make new selection? ty again

Comment: This does nothing: `$("#guildwars2").val();` and can be removed. See update for example of code you can use

Comment: thank you again for all your help and for the link to convert time, its now all working with time converted and placed into tables. everything looks good and all appears to be working fine much appreciated for all your help...